# Parsing huge xml file with invalid characters

Tags: python, xml, sax, elementtree

I have a 1GB xml file but it has some invalid characters like '&'. I want to parse it in Python. To do this, I used element tree as below:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as cElementTree                             

def main(): 
   context = cElementTree.iterparse('newscor.xml', events=("start", "end"))
   context = iter(context)
   event, root = context.__next__()

   for event, elem in context:
     if event == "start":
         if elem.tag == 'group': 
            elem.tail = None
            print ( elem.text)
         if elem.tag in ['group']:
            root.clear()                                               
main()
```

But it gave me following error in this line `for event, elem in context`:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

To handle this error, I tried to use lxml with `recover=True` for parser as described in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046240/parseerror-not-well-formed-invalid-token-using-celementtree). However, *iterparse()* does not have a parameter for parser in lxml.

Therefore, I also tried to use Sax in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325244/how-to-use-xml-sax-parser-to-read-and-write-a-large-xml) but I don't know where to use *escape* method.

What can I use to avoid invalid characters and parse this large file?

Comment: Try to use lxml with the HTML parser instead of the standard XML parser. The HTML parser is more forgiving with invalid input. Alternatively you can try to use [HTML tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/) in XML mode to repair the file. There even is a Python package for it.

Comment: or you can use perl/python's regex package to pre-process your xml file to get rid of the & sign.

Comment: I solved this problem with tidy tool (thanks Tomalak for your comment) Tidy tool converts special character & as &amp.