# How to use lxml with 0(1) memory?

Tags: python, lxml

I am trying to work with a ~72G XML file. I would like to convert it to CSV.

Here is the code that I assumed to be using iterators in the background as I might have read it somewhere about lxml.

```
from lxml import etree
import csv

file_name = "data/discogs_20231001_releases.xml"
# file_name = "data/sample.xml"


def handle_artists(artists):
    ret = []
    for artist in artists:
        artist_dict = {}
        for artist_tag in artist:
            if artist_tag.tag == "id":
                artist_dict["id"] = artist_tag.text
            elif artist_tag.tag == "name":
                artist_dict["name"] = artist_tag.text
        ret.append(artist_dict)
    return ret


events = ("start", "end")
context = etree.iterparse(file_name, events=events)

with open("data/discogs_20231001_releases.csv", "w") as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f=f, fieldnames=["release_id", "release_title"], delimiter="\t")
    w.writeheader()

    for action, elem in context:
        if action == "start" and elem.tag == "release":
            release_id = elem.get("id")
            release = {"release_id": release_id}
            for child in elem:
                tag = child.tag
                if tag == "title":
                    release["release_title"] = child.text
                elif tag == "artists":
                    # release["artists"] = handle_artists(child)
                    pass
            if release.get("release_title") != None:
                w.writerow(release)
```

When I run it I get:

```
Job 1, 'python release.py' terminated by signal SIGKILL (Forced quit)
```

I am not sure if I am making the mistake with the XML parser or the CSV writer.

Checking if a memory profiler can tell me exactly which one is the culprit.

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    49     25.8 MiB     25.8 MiB           1   @profile
    50                                         def process_event(elem):
    51     25.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       release = {}
    52     25.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       if elem.tag == "release":
    53                                                 release_id = elem.get("id")
    54                                                 release = {"release_id": release_id}
    55                                                 for child in elem:
    56                                                     tag = child.tag
    57                                                     if tag == "title":
    58                                                         release["release_title"] = child.text
    59                                                     elif tag == "artists":
    60                                                         # release["artists"] = handle_artists(child)
    61                                                         pass
    62     25.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return release
```

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    49    176.0 MiB    176.0 MiB           1   @profile
    50                                         def process_event(elem):
    51    176.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       release = {}
    52    176.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       if elem.tag == "release":
    53                                                 release_id = elem.get("id")
    54                                                 release = {"release_id": release_id}
    55                                                 for child in elem:
    56                                                     tag = child.tag
    57                                                     if tag == "title":
    58                                                         release["release_title"] = child.text
    59                                                     elif tag == "artists":
    60                                                         # release["artists"] = handle_artists(child)
    61                                                         pass
    62    176.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return release
```

The suggested solution with fast_iter does the following:

```
Python(99102,0x202e0e080) malloc: *** error for object 0x1338b7fc0: pointer being freed was not allocated
Python(99102,0x202e0e080) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
fish: Job 1, 'python release.py' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is lxml.etree.iterparse() eating up all my memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160418/why-is-lxml-etree-iterparse-eating-up-all-my-memory)

Comment: This is weird. Even using the suggested solution it is still using O(n) memory.

Comment: Since you don't actually seem to need the full document structure, I'd recommend a SAX style parser and a state machine instead.

Comment: Could you point me any example how to use SAX style parser with Python?

Comment: when searching for "SAX style parser with Python" (i.e. your exact words!) the first result I get is https://stackoverflow.com/q/42325244/1358308 which seems relevant

Comment: You should, if you have parsed the node, clear it from memory with `elem.clear()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a SAX-y reimplementation; it only stores exactly the information you're parsing at any given moment.

It could probably be made somewhat faster by not comparing the node path fully when we know we're not e.g. inside an `artist` tag, but that's left as an exercise to the reader.

```
from xml.sax import parse, ContentHandler


class DiscogsFileHandler(ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self, *, write_release):
        super().__init__()
        self.current_release = None
        self.current_artist = None
        self.write_release = write_release
        self.tag_stack = []
        self.char_buffer = ""

    @property
    def tag_path(self) -> tuple:
        return tuple(self.tag_stack)

    def startElement(self, name: str, attrs):
        self.tag_stack.append(name)
        path = self.tag_path
        if path == ("releases", "release"):
            assert not self.current_release
            self.current_release = {**dict(attrs), "artists": []}
        elif path == ("releases", "release", "artists", "artist"):
            assert not self.current_artist
            self.current_artist = dict(attrs)
            self.current_release["artists"].append(self.current_artist)

    def endElement(self, name: str):
        path = self.tag_path
        if path == ("releases", "release"):
            self.write_release(self.current_release)
            self.current_release = None
        if path == ("releases", "release", "title"):
            self.current_release["title"] = self.char_buffer
        if path == ("releases", "release", "artists", "artist", "name"):
            self.current_artist["name"] = self.char_buffer
        if path == ("releases", "release", "artists", "artist", "id"):
            self.current_artist["id"] = self.char_buffer
        if path == ("releases", "release", "artists", "artist"):
            self.current_artist = None
        assert self.tag_stack.pop() == name
        self.char_buffer = ""

    def characters(self, content: str):
        self.char_buffer += content


def write_release(rel: dict):
    print("Got release:", rel)
    # Your CSV writing code here...


parse("discogs.xml", DiscogsFileHandler(write_release=write_release))
```

The output is (e.g.; it doesn't write CSV)

```
Got release: {'id': '1', 'status': 'Accepted', 'artists': [{'id': '1', 'name': 'The Persuader'}], 'title': 'Stockholm'}
Got release: {'id': '2', 'status': 'Accepted', 'artists': [{'id': '2', 'name': 'Mr. James Barth & A.D.'}], 'title': "Knockin' Boots (Vol 2 Of 2)"}
Got release: {'id': '3', 'status': 'Accepted', 'artists': [{'id': '3', 'name': 'Josh Wink'}], 'title': 'Profound Sounds Vol. 1'}
Got release: {'id': '4', 'status': 'Accepted', 'artists': [{'id': '21', 'name': 'Faze Action'}], 'title': 'Moving Cities'}
Got release: {'id': '5', 'status': 'Accepted', 'artists': [{'id': '22', 'name': 'Datacide'}], 'title': 'Flowerhead'}
Got release: {'id': '6', 'status': 'Accepted', 'artists': [{'id': '2', 'name': 'Mr. James Barth & A.D.'}], 'title': "Knockin' Boots (Vol 1 Of 2)"}
Got release: {'id': '7', 'status': 'Accepted', 'artists': [{'id': '28', 'name': 'Moonchildren'}], 'title': 'Moonchildren EP'}
Got release: {'id': '8', 'status': 'Accepted', 'artists': [{'id': '29', 'name': 'Sweet Abraham'}], 'title': 'Spreading Outward EP'}
Got release: {'id': '9', 'status': 'Accepted', 'artists': [{'id': '33', 'name': 'Blue Six'}], 'title': 'Pure'}
Got release: {'id': '10', 'status': 'Accepted', 'artists': [{'id': '36', 'name': 'Lovetronic'}], 'title': 'You Are Love'}
```

I didn't care to download the full file, so I did

```
curl -fSL 'https://discogs-data-dumps.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/data/2023/discogs_20231001_releases.xml.gz' | head -c 10000000 | gzcat | xmllint --recover - > discogs.xml
```

to grab at least some of it.

To prove this actually does streaming, you can change `"discogs.xml"` to `sys.stdin.buffer` in the code and actually stream in the file from the Internet to the program:

```
curl -fSL 'https://discogs-data-dumps.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/data/2023/discogs_20231001_releases.xml.gz' | gzcat | python so77452645.py
```

Comment: This is amazing, thanks!